Translating "and" when it connotes a combined meaning
How would "and" be translated into Chinese if the constituent nouns add up to a combined effect - like "fair, reasonable and non-discriminatory" or "life, liberty and the pursuit of happiness" - assuming that each of these parts is not a checklist, but that they are combined into a unity concept.

I would take care looking for simple solutions for translating and to Chinese. That can be tricky!

constituent nouns?

fair, reasonable, non-discriminatory are descriptive words.

combined effect?

life, liberty, pursuit are names of intangible concepts.
and = 而且 and = ,
The system is archaic and unfair and needs changing.
这个制度早已过时而且不公平，需要改变。
and = 、and = 且
The room was dim and cool and quiet.
这房间昏暗、阴冷且安静。
is = 又 and = 又 and = ,
Steve is tall and thin and has brown hair.
史蒂夫又高又瘦，长着棕色的头发。
and = (没有)
Rhythm and blues mutated into rock and roll.
节奏布鲁斯演变成为摇滚乐。

and = (没有) Governments like doing this XD, then created a illusion of an overly long sentence

The most natural way of expressing unitary phrases is to list their components in paratactic sequence. Whether nouns, verbs or adjectives, groups of words that form a semantic unit are simply combined serially. That means no conjunction is needed. See, for example:

福寿 = fortune and longevity.
高富帅 = tall, rich and handsome.
健康长寿 = good health and long life.
公平合理 = fair and reasonable.

When the components are longer, more numerous or otherwise unwieldy, as is often the case in translation (which may require using longer compounds to keep as faithful to the original as possible), the list can be broken up by either an enumeration comma (、 ), e.g.:

生命权、自由权、追求幸福权 = Life, Liberty and the pursuit of Happiness.
公平、合理、无歧视 = fair, reasonable and non-discriminatory.
自由、平等、博爱 = Liberty, Equality and Fraternity.

and/or a conjunction like 又/且/和 (between adjectives/statives) or 与/及/和 (between nouns), e.g.:

有理由又有根据 = reasonable and compelling.
和平、正义与强大机构 = peace, justice and strong institutions.

Conjunctions like 又 and 且 can also be used to make emphatic pairings of adjectives/statives, in which case they're usually introduced by 又 and 既, respectively:

又高又大 = big and tall.
既深且广 = wide and deep.


"and" equates "和" in Chinese, a conjunction to connect several component words in a single sentence. Note, depending on the context, it can mean "加/加上/及" also.

"fair, reasonable and non-discriminatory" - "公平, 合理和非歧视的"

"life, liberty and the pursuit of happiness" - "生命, 自由和追求幸福



和 is not the only character that combines terms. Similar characters include 與、及、並 and 同, just to name a few.

Quite often you don't simply translate English into Chinese.
For example, fair, reasonable and non-discriminatory = 公正、合理、公平

This is exactly my point.  This term is standardized,and is inconsistently translated by Chinse courts and agencies, including senior leaders in their speeches.  It is an integrated concept:.  The translation you offered is actually one of the least common - the most common is 公平、合理、无歧视。  The Standardization Administration of China, the NPC in its drafting guidelines, an the SPC in its guidelines on drafting up causes of action, all would mandate a conjunction between reasonable and non-discriminatory. As a standardized international term, the translation should be consistent and clear.
